How to state the compatible versions for torch and cuda in the requirements.txt file in a single line for Python?
I would like to leverage the Python (3.8.2) libraries / frameworks, which are PyTorch and CUDA. I want to rely on the compatible versions stated by using ~= for both of these on a single line. The exact declaration (long form) in the requirements.txt file is as follows:
torch==1.13.1+cu117
However, I want to utilise compatible versions denoted by ~=, as shown below:
torch~=1.13+cu11
That is, the torch to be installed can be one of 1.13.1, 1.13.2, etc. (i.e. 1.13.*) whereas cuda might be one of 11.1, 11.2, ..., 11.7, and so on (i.e. 11.*). Is the example I have shown above the correct usage? If not, what is the proper usage for that version compatibility? Otherwise, can I not state the compatible versions for the two (dependent) libraries on the same line in the requirements.txt file?

This doesn't work with just torch==1.13.1+cu117 in your requirements.txt.
According to the official documentation, you would need to run e.g.
pip install torch==1.13.1+cu117 torchvision==0.14.1+cu117 torchaudio==0.13.1 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117

In particular, you need the --extra-index-url if you want to control the cuda version. So your requirements.txt needs to look like this for e.g. cu117
--extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117
torch==1.13.1+cu117

You can have more than one --extra-index-url in the requirements.txt, so this is how you can allow several versions to be considered:
--extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116
--extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117
torch~=1.13.1

